# How do I reference the F# binding and steps assembly correctly in the config file.?

Tags: c#, selenium, f#, specflow, f#-interactive

Basically developed BDD specflow using specflow and C#,now looking to convert this C# to F# as F# being fuctional domain language.

Didnt find any updated videos for BDD with F# hence trying to convert BDD Specflow C# to BDD Specflow F# using Binding.Can anyone detail me the exact steps how can i do binding of specflow written in C# to F#?